# Injecting a factory method using StructureMap

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap

I'm using a [wrapper for the ASP.NET Membership provider](http://mvcmembership.codeplex.com/) so that I can have more loosely coupled usage of the library. I'm wanting to use StructureMap to provide true IoC, but I'm having trouble with configuring it with a User-to-Profile factory object that I'm using to put instantiate the profile in the context of a user.  Here's the relevant details, first the interface and wrapper from the library:

```
// From ASP.Net MVC Membership Starter Kit
public interface IProfileService
{
    object this[string propertyName] { get; set; }
    void SetPropertyValue(string propertyName, object propertyValue);
    object GetPropertyValue(string propertyName);
    void Save();
}

public class AspNetProfileBaseWrapper : IProfileService
{
    public AspNetProfileBaseWrapper(string email) {}

    // ...
}
```

Next, a repository for interacting with a particular property in the profile data:

```
class UserDataRepository : IUserDataRepository
{
    Func<MembershipUser, IProfileService> _profileServiceFactory;

    // takes the factory as a ctor param 
            // to configure it to the context of the given user
    public UserDataRepository(
              Func<MembershipUser, IProfileService> profileServiceFactory)
    {
        _profileServiceFactory = profileServiceFactory;
    }

    public object GetUserData(MembershipUser user)
    {
        // profile is used in context of a user like so:
        var profile = _profileServiceFactory(user);
        return profile.GetPropertyValue("UserData");
    }
}
```

Here's my first attempt at providing a StructureMap registry config, but it obviously doesn't work:

```
public class ProfileRegistry : Registry
{
    public ProfileRegistry()
    {
        // doesn't work, still wants MembershipUser and a default ctor for AspNetProfileBaseWrapper
        For<IProfileService>().Use<AspNetProfileBaseWrapper>();
    }
}
```

Theoretically how I'd like to register it would look something like:

```
// syntax failure :)
For<Func<MembershipUser, IProfileService>>()
  .Use<u => new AspNetProfileBaseWrapper(u.Email)>();
```

...where I can define the factory object in the configuration.  This is obviously not valid syntax.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this?  Should I be using some other pattern to allow constructing my UserDataRepository in the context of a user?  Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I had looked at the overloads for Use, I would have found

```
Use(Func<IContext> func);
```

...which I can use as:

```
For<IUserService>().Use(s =>
   new AspNetMembershipProviderWrapper(Membership.Provider));
```