# Working with multiple Db`s. How to inject DbContexts connected to different Dbs?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, structuremap

Using these two following link, I have implemented my project with Repo, Unit of work, EF, DI.

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/814768/CRUD-Operations-Using-the-Generic-Repository-Patte
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/838097/CRUD-Operations-Using-the-Generic-Repository-Pat

But after a while because of legacy databases, I had to expand my project for two databases.
But so far I could not expand my project so that can work with two databases.
Could anyone please provide me with any solution regarding working with multiple databases based on mentioned links?

Thank you in advance.

**Update**

**Core**

```
   **Financial Database**

public class Vou : Entity
  {
     public Nullable<long> Num { get; set; }
     public string Subj { get; set; }
  }

   **Trading Database**

public class Goods : Entity
  {
    public long Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
  }
```

**Data**

```
public interface IDbContext
    {
        IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : Entity;
        int SaveChanges();
    }


public class IocDbContext : DbContext, IDbContext
    {
        public IocDbContext()
            : base("name=FinancialEntities")
        {
        }

        public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : Entity
        {
            return base.Set<TEntity>();
        }
    }


 public interface IRepository< TEntity>
    {
        TEntity Get(int id);
    }



public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity 
    {
        protected readonly DbContext context;
        private IDbSet<T> _entities;

        public Repository(IocDbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            this.context.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple databases means connection per dbContext. In both articles DbContext is created like this :

```
   public EFDbContext()
       : base("name=DbConnectionString")
   {
   }
```

and then in the Repos ctor :

```
    public Repository(EFDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
```

What you need is another ctor in EFDbContext like this :

```
    public EFDbContext (DbConnection connection)
        : base(connection, true)
    {

    }
```

and pass it in the Repo like this :

```
    public Repository(IDbContextProvider contextProvider)
    {
        this._contextProvider = contextProvider;
    }
```

and you need the IDbContextProvider like so :

```
    public interface IDbContextProvider
    {
        DbContext Current(); // implicitly provided (from current HttpContext)
        DbContext Specific(string dbName); // the caller provides it
    }
```

and inside the implementation of IDbContextProvider you can put the logic you need in order create your particular db connection. I use such an implementation for multiple db`s which works fine.

As a rule of thumb : "When you need another level of indirection you are going to need another level of abstraction."

In your case you need another level of indirection, not just a single db context, but multiple. So the paths multiply at the level of the connection :

- user1-db1
- user1-db2
- userN-dbM
- ....

Therefore the meat goes into IDbContextProvider.Current().

How? For example, you can call IDbContextProvider.Current() and get the dbName by some url-to-db mapping. Another approach - get the user id from the cookie and make userid-to-db mapping. Depends on your specific case.

**UPDATE**
Here is an example with Castle Windsor :

```
 private static DbContextAdapter DbContextAdapterFactoryMethod(IKernel k, ComponentModel cm, CreationContext c)
    {
        IEfLogger logger = k.Resolve<IEfLogger>();
        if (c.HasAdditionalArguments)
        {
            IDbModel model = (IDbModel)c.AdditionalArguments["model"];
            IDbConnection connection = (IDbConnection)c.AdditionalArguments["connection"];
            return DbContextAdapter.CreateCompanyContext(model, connection, logger);
        }
        else
        {
            return DbContextAdapter.CreateMainContext(logger);
        }
    }
```

In the example above the creation of DbContext is driven by parameters. There is no default constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your time and consideration, but to be honest I could not realize your point.   Also If you meant, I pass context  to the repository , What do I do in case of any join between two tables of different databases. Could you please clarify more for me?

Comment: Great thanks for your help. But actually I've got more confused. I have updated my question with my code. Could you please correct my code based on your advice so that work with "Trading Database" as well?

Comment: Do you use tour repositories inside a service?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I use structure map for IoC. My way is very similar to the link that I mentioned in my question. codeproject.com/Articles/838097/… Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: There is a mismatch between the implementation in articles and the requirements at hand. By that I mean that in the articles the DbContext has one ctor which has defined connection string but the requirements are for two different contexts with two different connection strings. The solution is to get the instantiation of the DbContexts out of the repository by introducing DbContextFactory which provides IDbContext to the repository and not the concrete DbContext itself. Then in the factory you can make the identification step - "Which concrete DbContext should I push to the Repository?"

Comment: @ Ognyan Dimitrov :Thanks. Actually I need to use both of DbContext. Could you please change my code with your idea so I can understand what you mean?

Comment: I can not update your code because I have not used Structure Map and I do not know how to implement a factory.  Examples for what I say [here](http://docs.structuremap.net/RetrievingServices.htm), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135140/injecting-a-factory-method-using-structuremap), [here!!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671078/registering-method-on-generic-factory-with-structuremap) and if you search more for 'Structure Map factory' you will get even more.

Comment: Thanks. Please update my code with every IoC that you have worked with that. The only things is important for me is that how this code can changed so that it can work with two Database. Like something you said about DbContextFactory. I am just looking for a design and architecture of classes as I can work with repository and unit of work and IoC and **two** databases. Thank again

Comment: Can I please have your idea about that?